# SQL Count by group by item

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query

```
select count(t1.contactid) [Count],
             case
                when f.item like '%yes%' then 'Yes'
                when f.item like '%Correct%' then 'Yes'  
                when f.item like '%None%' then 'No'
                when f.item like '% Notask%' then 'No'
              end as Items

      from table1 t1
           join table2 t2 on t1.contactid =  t2.contactid
            
      group by f.item
```

How do I group  by each item

```
the result

    Count       items
    10           No
    20           No
    1           Yes
    1           Yes
    3           Yes
    1           Yes
```

My goal to group No and Yes so it should look like

```
    Count     Items
    30          No
    6           Yes
```

Thank you

Comment: `f` is not defined so your query will return an error.

Comment: I mean 6 on on Yes ad f replace  t2

Comment: . . You can edit the question (but I already changed that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat the `case` expression in the `group by`.  Or use a subquery or CTE.  But I like `apply` for this purpose:

```
select v.items, count(t1.contactid) as [Count]
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.contactid =  t2.contactid cross apply
     (values (case when f.item like '%yes%' then 'Yes'
                   when f.item like '%Correct%' then 'Yes'  
                   when f.item like '%None%' then 'No'
                   when f.item like '% Notask%' then 'No'
              end)
     ) v(Items)
group by v.items
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select v.items, count(t1.contactid) as [Count]
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.contactid =  t2.contactid cross apply
     (values (case when f.item like '%yes%' then 'Yes'
                   when f.item like '%Correct%' then 'Yes'  
                   when f.item like '%None%' then 'No'
                   when f.item like '% Notask%' then 'No'
              end)
     ) v(Items)
group by v.items
```